# How do I prevent '....com via 2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com' from showing up in the FROM field when sending email from AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

How do I prevent the '....com via 2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com' from showing up in the header when sending email from AppEngine? I'm sending to myself yet it still shows.

I found this page which says

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en-GB&ctx=mail&authuser=1#

> I'm a sender and I don't want my recipients to see the "via" link. What can I do?
>
> Gmail checks whether emails are correctly authenticated. If your messages are sent by a bulk mailing vendor or by third-party affiliates, please publish an SPF record that includes the IPs of the vendor or affiliates which send your messages and sign your messages with a DKIM signature that is associated with your domain.

Yet looking at the headers, it shows that SPF and DKIM are already set and passed!

```
Return-Path: <3OIblUgoJBXcWVif-mZXjibhVdg.XjhXcgjZjidsYZqx.Xjh@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3OIblUgoJBXcWVif-mZXjibhVdg.XjhXcgjZjidsYZqx.Xjh@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates 209.85.212.72 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.212.72;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3OIblUgoJBXcWVif-mZXjibhVdg.XjhXcgjZjidsYZqx.Xjh@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates 209.85.212.72 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=3OIblUgoJBXcWVif-mZXjibhVdg.XjhXcgjZjidsYZqx.Xjh@2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=mime-version:reply-to:message-id:date:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=chRsCD+FjUjL41bfEeXlAef5gWxlIYtGdgQGKtsk5nQ=;
        b=g+3WZtFRy1F6d5cRX94eRcKaNk4yg8M1OS/qUDV9ju8El7XIxE5KGsR+6Jo5rOB5ZX
         g3U3Gb9KRTOm3FQ7d7X3mVbZUauuZOYzmpijJ65R0Qnc5U0sljIB5IYmKropnxJHIeyi
         DOuaL6FFMfrDclpWf1E9o8eXclkAxTdllRTQxjWrc91vucH89dMfs8jCF/KmWUFMECuX
         Z69zmxKEnNn0FXZXP5i0FodxfZlb6qn7OSKeE4MVpehBIA7l0bsVv8pLOWQmBWSrQHqr
         fD9dlC0r3+hYmYR8lxrR+7mtikt+hOnD3SIV7Vh0+MtZH3rOqKT5uJo262SGbD66Ckgf
         yZ3A==
```

The code is rather mild

```
    Message message = prepareMessage();
    Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: What domains do you send mails from? Your custom domain or gmail?

Comment: @PeterKnego Email is being sent from an AppEngine app. The domain is app-name.appspot.com.

Answer (score 1):

Domains that want to reliably send emails should have [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) set in their DNS configuration. This is needed to that you email does not get marked as spam.

If you send from @gmail.com, than Google sets this. But if you send mail from you custom domain, then you need to set this on your own.

In your case it seems that you send from custom domain, so google adds a "via" header along with it's own DKIM/SPF records so that this mail has better spam protection.

Comment: But the email is sent from app-name.appspot.com, and we don't have DNS control over that domain because it belongs to Google! The email is not marked as spam.